# another unsupported format character error

Tags: django, internationalization

i have a template section like this,

```
{% blocktrans with poster=link.posted_by timesince=link.posted_at|timesince %}Posted by {{poster}}, {{timesince}} ago.{% endblocktrans %}
```

and i am getting:

```
Caught ValueError while rendering: unsupported format character '?' (0xf6) at index 35
```

error from that line. What i am missing here? I think problem is at the timesince... what is right behaviour print it correctly?

Note: I tried this also:

```
{% blocktrans with poster=link.posted_by posted_at=link.posted_at %}Posted by {{poster}}, {{posted_at|timesince}} ago.{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: What locales are used by the server and browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried this way:-

1. create locale folders (some thing like this)

   `/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`

   here **"it"** is locale name (for italian language), **Examples:**  it, de_AT, es, pt_BR
2. `django-admin.py makemessages -l it`

Refer this URL's for more info:-

**http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter18/**

**http://www.paolocorti.net/2009/12/18/the-pinax-tutorial-3-internationalization-of-the-application/**

**https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/**

Comment: Yes i did, my translations are working well, only that line gives error.